# Bytebuddy - Intercept java.lang.RuntimeException constructor

Tags: java, agent, byte-buddy

Iam trying to intercept the constructor `RuntimeException(String)`. Iam trying to use `Advice` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232301/bytebuddy-intercept-java-net-serversocket-constructor/61246771#61246771) and shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747219/byte-buddy-advice-onmethodexit-constructor-retransformation). But the methods `onEnter(String message)` or `onExit(String message)`. My instrumenting class (inside a different jar):

```
public class Instrumenting {

private static final String CLASS_NAME = "java.lang.RuntimeException";

public static void instrument(Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("[Instrumenting] starting to instrument '" + CLASS_NAME + "'");

    instrumentation.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(new JarFile("C:\\Users\\Moritz\\Instrumenting\\dist\\Instrumenting.jar"));

    File temp = Files.createTempDirectory("tmp").toFile();
    ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.of(temp, ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.Target.BOOTSTRAP, instrumentation).inject(Collections.singletonMap(
        new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(RuntimeExceptionIntercept.class),
        ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(RuntimeExceptionIntercept.class)));


    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
            .with(new AgentBuilder.InjectionStrategy.UsingInstrumentation(instrumentation, temp))
            .type(ElementMatchers.named(CLASS_NAME))

            .transform((DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription td, ClassLoader cl, JavaModule jm) -> 
                    builder
                            .visit(Advice.to(RuntimeExceptionIntercept.class)
                                            .on(ElementMatchers.isConstructor())
                            )
            ).installOn(instrumentation);

    System.out.println("[Instrumenting] done");
}

public static class RuntimeExceptionIntercept {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void onEnter(String message) throws Exception {
        System.err.println("onEnter: " + message);
    }

    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static void onExit(String message) throws Exception {
        System.err.println("onExit: " + message);
    }
}
```

}

How its called:

```
public class Main {

public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
    Instrumenting.instrument(instrumentation);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    new RuntimeException("message");
}
```

}

Output:

```
[Instrumenting] starting to instrument 'java.lang.RuntimeException'
[Instrumenting] done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The class is already loaded when your agent is running and you have not specified for example `RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORM`. Therefore, your agent will not reconsider already loaded classes. Note that you should set a more specific ignore matcher then that.

By the way, advice is inlined in the target class, your injection is not required.

Comment: Adding `RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORM` did not fix my problem. What else could be wrong here? :/

Comment: Have you added a listener to see if there's an error?

Comment: Your are right, I added a listener and got the following Error `No advice defined by class instrumenting.Instrumenting$RuntimeExceptionIntercept`

Comment: Is your advice class possibly also on the bootstrap loader? This would explain why the annotations are not discovered.

Comment: You are right, I moved the class `RuntimeExceptionIntercept` to another file which fixed the error. But now Iam getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot assign java.lang.Throwable arg0 to class javalang.String`. Do I have to offer an `onEnter` and `onExit` for each constructor of `RuntimeException`? Or what am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: When changing `public static void onEnter(String message) throws Exception` to `public static void onEnter(@Advice.AllArguments Object[] args) throws Exception` the error disappears but the method is never called.

Comment: The method is indeed never called, it is only used as a template. If not annotating the argument, Byte Buddy assumes that it references the first argument of the instrumented method.